# Line integral of vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

> The vector field
> $$\vec{F}(x,y)=(e^x-y)\vec{i} + (x-e^y)\vec{i}$$
> goes
> goes around $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $ (0,3)$, $(-1,3)$, $(-2,2)$, $ (-2,1)$, $(-3,0)$ in order
> find the line integral.

How do I solve this question? Is there a easy way or should I use manual labor and split the segments?

Comment: Hint. It is a gradient vector field plus a rotational vector field

Comment: Do you know Green's Theorem yet?

Comment: I made an error on this. I assumed by looking at the coordinates that this was an octagon. Simple error. Do they specify whether you go back to $(0,0)$ at the end? Or do you stop at $(-3,0)$. If you go all the way around, then you will still apply Green's Theorem, and use the same method, but just find the area enclosed by the non-octagonal region. If you don't go back to the origin, you're going to have to do each line segment separately. The partial derivatives adding up to 2 makes me think it should be going all the way around. Do you go back to $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Cjw123 we can close off the curve and still apply Green's theorem indirectly to optimize the solution. That will save integrating over multiple line segments.